# typescript and dealing with FileReader

Tags: typescript

I am trying to read a file on the client side as an array buffer. Here is my code.

```
for (var index = 0; index < input.files.length;index++) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  console.log(input.files[index].name);
  reader.onload = () => {
    var data:ArrayBuffer = reader.result;
    console.log(data.toString().length);
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[index])
}
```

However my editor complains that reader.result returns (string | ArrayBuffer)

However if I remove type type from the data. I am unable to use ArrayBuffer specific methods like byteLength.

How do I force the reader.result to be an ArrayBuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you know TS is pretty dope xD. Write your code like you would normally write and it will interpret your code and things will roll.

```
function foo() {
    return (
        Math.random() < 0.5
            ? "damn dis shit wild"
            : new ArrayBuffer(1024)
    )
}

let bar = foo(); // string | ArrayBuffer
if (bar instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    // bar is only ArrayBuffer in this block :O *.*
    bar.byteLength; // <-- no error
} else {
    bar.startsWith("damn") // <-- no error
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Math.random()%20%3C%200.5%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20%22damn%20dis%20shit%20wild%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20new%20ArrayBuffer(1024)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20foo()%3B%0D%0Aif%20(bar%20instanceof%20ArrayBuffer)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20bar%20is%20only%20ArrayBuffer%20in%20this%20block%20%3AO%20*.*%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar.byteLength%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20no%20error%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar.startsWith(%22damn%22)%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20no%20error%0D%0A%7D). I guess this is what you wanted?

Btw you also mentioned by "force" huh so normal assertion would work too, but is not recommended because it can give runtime errors if `bar` is `string`.

```
function foo() {
    return (
        Math.random() < 0.5
            ? "damn dis shit wild"
            : new ArrayBuffer(1024)
    )
}

let bar = <ArrayBuffer>foo();
bar.byteLength; // <-- no error
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Math.random()%20%3C%200.5%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20%22damn%20dis%20shit%20wild%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20new%20ArrayBuffer(1024)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20%3CArrayBuffer%3Efoo()%3B%0D%0Abar.byteLength%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20no%20error)

Comment: OK this worked but I have no idea how the if statement is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @TommieJones Well it's not actually getting evaluated. TS uses the abstract syntax tree to do this. But it's very basic, meaning writing `if ([bar instanceof ArrayBuffer][0] === true)` instead of `if (bar instanceof ArrayBuffer)` will not work even tho it does the same thing.

Comment: Someone upvoted this, so I'm getting back to the above comment and it's important to mention the way it works is `instanceof` is a "type guard" in TS, you can make you own with `is`. so the above comment is not very accurate, it does kinda get "evaluated", not in the wild but in the type context like how all complex types do